# Countdown Function Only Returning One Value

Tags: python, countdown

What is wrong with the second function?

```
def count(n):
  return [i for i in range (n,-1,-1)]
```

gives me the accurate result of `[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]` but

```
def count(n):
  for i in range (n,-1,-1):
      return i
```

always returns `n`.

Comment: What do you think `return` is doing?

Comment: You don't see any difference (besides *range* arguments) between the 2 snippets? It should only return *n* because you exit at 1st iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As people have said in the comments, return stops the function and returns the value. Use a [generator](https://realpython.com/introduction-to-python-generators/) if you want to do something like this, but not exit the function. Also, it is recommended that you use 4 spaces for indentation by [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), the official Python style guide.

```py
def count(n):
    for i in range(n, -1, -1):
        yield i

print(list(count(5)))
```